# All devices on my network redirect me to an old domain

Tags: redirect, cache, domain, dns

I have moved my website from wordpress.com to a wordpress.org platform. I ordered a new host, meanwhile keeping the old domain. It have been a day since the dns servers were updated and according to my host provider everything is good. The problem I'm facing is that absolutely every device on my network, including mobiles connected trough wi-fi, keeps seeing the older domain when trying to access the website. Everybody else are managing to enter the new domain with the new theme,posts and etc. I tried flushing the dns, cleared every browser cache but still nothing is changed.

Comment: Did you flush the DNS on the router/modem directly? This is probably the culprit. If you're on Mac/Linux, try `dig www.example.com` and you will see the TTL of the DNS

Comment: I'm using Windows. I flushed the dns using ipconfig /flushdns in the command prompt running as administrator as shown in many tutorials around the web, but still did not help.

Comment: You're (probably) only flushing your computer's DNS cache, not the one of the router/modem. Try searching "fritzbox flush dns" (or whatever system you're using). Anyway, this is out of the scope of this site, as it is not related to WordPress at all